# jquery mobile 1.4 wont allow an external link to open from app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, href

I'm creating a small webapp using jquery mobile 1.4 and php. It displays customer information and one of the bits of information may be a website. I want the user to be able to click on a link and be taken to the website, preferably opening it within the webapp itself rather than redirecting to a new page. However when I try to do this I get the error:

> The requested URL /webapp/www.google.com was not found on this
>   server

Here is my code:

```
<a href='www.google.com' rel='external' class='ui-btn' data-transition='pop' >Browse</a>
```

I cant understand why it's trying to open the page within my webapp folder rather than directing it straight to the webpage. If I remove

> rel='external'

it just gives me a load error on screen rather than a full error message.

Does anyone have any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer - here it is for anyone else who might have the same issue:

some PHP to deal with $number (the web address)

```
 $url = $number;
 if(substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://') {
     $url = 'http://' . $url;
  }
```

the link

```
<a href='$url' class='ui-btn' data-transition='pop' >Browse</a>
```

Any ideas on how to get the external page to stay within the webapp - possibly in a popup?